# How Does Azure Cosmos DB APIs maps in CLI and Azure Portal

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I see on Microsoft's docs that when creating a Cosmos DB account from CLI:
az cosmos DB create --name --resourcegroup [--kind {GlobalDocumentDB, MongoDB, Parse}]

But when we create a Cosmos DB account from the Portal we get 5 API options:
SQL, Mongo DB, Table, Cassandra, Gremlin.

But, how do these 3 kinds from CLI are mapped to these 5 APIs in the Portal?
I am new to Cosmos DB so confused. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The database API's in Cosmos are driven by a combination of the `--kind` property as well as values in a string array called `--capabilities`.

When creating a new SQL or MongoDB API account you use a combination of "GlobalDocumentDB" for SQL and "MongoDB" resepectively.

To create a Gremlin, Cassandra and Table API account, you specify `--kind=GlobalDocumentDB` and `--capabilities=EnableGremlin` or `--capabilities=EnableCassandra` or `--capabilities=EnableTable`

You can see this in action by looking at the Azure CLI samples for each of the database API's in Cosmos DB here below.

- [SQL API
  Samples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql/cli-samples)
- [MongoDB API
  Samples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/mongodb/cli-samples)
- [Gremlin API
  Samples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/graph/cli-samples)
- [Cassandra API
  Samples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/cassandra/cli-samples)
- [Table API
  Samples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/table/cli-samples)

You can also find all these in a single GitHub repo here, [Azure Cosmos DB CLI Samples Repo](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-cli-samples/tree/master/cosmosdb)

Comment: Thank you very much Mark for clearing this. Can you please also tell the significance of --kind=Parse while creating cosmos db account

Comment: Parse is an extremely old API that was supported when the service first launched as DocumentDB. It has since been deprecated but we never got around to removing it.

Comment: Thank you for making it all clear